# Cannot prove in Dafny that variance(x)>=0

Tags: covariance, assertion, proof, theorem-proving, dafny

I would like to prove in Dafny that `variance(x)` (i.e., `covariance(x,x)`) is `>=0`. Note that we define `covariance(x,y)` as: `1/N*Summation{i=1 to N}{(x_i-x_mean)*(y_i-y_mean)}`, where `N` is the number of elements of `x` and `y`.

Let us define covariance in Dafny as in [Proving a covariance inequality in Dafny, use contradiction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74156826/proving-a-covariance-inequality-in-dafny-use-contradiction):

```
//calculates the sum of all elements of a sequence
function method sum_seq(s:seq<real>): (res:real)
  ensures (forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| ==> s[i] >= 0.0) ==> res>=0.0
  decreases s;
{
  if s == [] then 0.0 else s[0] + sum_seq(s[1..])
}

//calculates the mean of a sequence
function method mean_fun(s:seq<real>): (res:real) 
  requires |s| >= 1;
  decreases |s|;
  ensures (forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| ==> s[i] >= 0.0) ==> res>=0.0

{
    sum_seq(s) / (|s| as real)
}
   
//from a sequence x, it constructs a=[x[0]-x_mean, x[1]-x_mean...]
function construct_list (x:seq<real>, m:real) : (a:seq<real>)
  requires |x| >= 1
  ensures |x|==|a|
  {
    if |x| == 1 then [x[0]-m]
    else [x[0]-m] + construct_list(x[1..],m)
  }

//it performs the Summation of the covariance
//note that a=[x[0]-x_mean, x[1]-x_mean...] and b=[y[0]-y_mean, y[1]-y_mean...]
function {:fuel 2} product(a: seq<real>, b: seq<real>) : real
  requires |a| == |b|
{
  if |a| == 0 then 0.0
  else a[0] * b[0] + product(a[1..], b[1..])
}

//covariance is the Summation divided by the number of elements
function cov(x: seq<real>, y: seq<real>) : (res:real)
  requires |x| == |y|
  requires |x| >= 1
  ensures cov(x,y) == product(construct_list(x, mean_fun(x)),construct_list(y, mean_fun(y))) / (|x| as real)
  //i.e., ensures cov(x,y) == product(a,b) / (|x| as real)
{
  var x_mean := mean_fun(x);
  var y_mean := mean_fun(y);

  var a := construct_list(x, x_mean);
  var b := construct_list(y, y_mean);

  product(a,b) / (|a| as real)
}
```

Thus, to prove `cov(x,y)>=0`, I directly try the following:

```
//variance (i.e., Cov(x,x)) is always positive
lemma covarianceItself_positive(a:seq<real>) 
   requires |a| >= 1
   requires forall i :: 0 <= i < |a| ==> a[i] >= 0.0
   ensures cov(a,a) >= 0.0
   {}
```

Which does not verify on its own. So I verify its base case and then realize that is suffices to prove that `product(a,a)>=0.0`, which is stated in Lemma  `productItself_positive(a)`:

```
lemma covarianceItself_positive(a:seq<real>) 
   requires |a| >= 1
   requires forall i :: 0 <= i < |a| ==> a[i] >= 0.0
   ensures cov(a,a) >= 0.0
   {
       if (|a|==1){
           assert cov(a,a) >= 0.0;
       }
       else{
           productItself_positive(a);
       }
   }
```

Where `productItself_positive` is the following:

```
lemma productItself_positive(a:seq<real>)
   requires |a| >= 1
   requires forall i :: 0 <= i < |a| ==> a[i] >= 0.0
   ensures product(construct_list(a, mean_fun(a)),construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))) >= 0.0  
   {}
```

I am trying to make a proof for this Lemma, so I started a calculation. My problems are that (1) Dafny reports that `a calculation step might not hold`; and (2) Dafny is easily getting stuck while verifying, so I do not know whether I am following the a right idea. My advances so far are as follows:

```
lemma productItself_positive(a:seq<real>)
   requires |a| >= 1
   requires forall i :: 0 <= i < |a| ==> a[i] >= 0.0
   ensures product(construct_list(a, mean_fun(a)),construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))) >= 0.0  
   {
       if (|a|==1){
           assert product(construct_list(a, mean_fun(a)),construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))) >= 0.0;
       } 
       else {
           calc >= {
               product(construct_list(a, mean_fun(a)),construct_list(a, mean_fun(a)));
               {
                 assert forall x:real :: forall y:real :: (x>=0.0 && y>=0.0) ==> (x*y>=0.0);
                 assert forall x:real :: forall y:real :: (x>=0.0 && y>=0.0) ==> (x+y>=0.0);

                 assert construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] * construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] >= 0.0;
                 productItself_positive(a[1..]);
                 //assert product(a[1..],a[1..]) >= 0.0; //Loops forever

               }
               //construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] * construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] + product(a[1..],a[1..]); //This should hold, but says that previous calculation does not hold
               //{assume construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] * construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] + product(a[1..],a[1..]) >= 0.0;}
               //construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] * construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] + product(a[1..],a[1..]) >= 0.0;
               //Knowing that construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] * construct_list(a, mean_fun(a))[0] >= 0.0 and that product(a[1..],a[1..]), their sum should be >=0.0
               0.0;
           }
       } 
   }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is straight forward way to do this. First add postcondition in product that it is positive if both array are same, dafny able to verify it without any help

```
function {:fuel 2} product(a: seq<real>, b: seq<real>) : real
  requires |a| == |b|
  ensures a == b ==> product(a, b) >= 0.0
{
  if |a| == 0 then 0.0
  else a[0] * b[0] + product(a[1..], b[1..])
}
```

Then use the fact that covariance is product of two equal array

```
lemma self_cov_is_positive(a: seq<real>)
 requires |a| >= 1
 ensures cov(a, a) >= 0.0
 {
    var a_list := construct_list(a, mean_fun(a));
    assert cov(a, a) == product(a_list, a_list) / (|a| as real);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! As a side question, do you know what was wrong with my `calc` idea? I mean, I am really surprised because I just tested the `ensures a == b ==> product(a, b) >= 0.0` of `product` adding `{:induction false}` to see if Dafny needs `calc`; but it still holds!

Comment: When you call `productItself_positive(a[1..])` it will calculate mean of a[1..]  and mean of a might not be equal to mean of a[1..]. This is one of major problem I see. So recursive hypothesis is subtracting different value